# Table TD resize using jquery.ui re-sizable event in percentage

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

As trying to resize the columns and row of the table using jquery.ui re-sizable event. Some how i have achieved to resize but when i have applied 100% for table in the CSS resizable doesn't work as expected. Below is my code and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/4b5g328q/2/) .
Thanks in Advance

```
$('.table td').resizable({
resize: function(event,ui) {
            var col = $(this).index()+1;
        $(this).closest('table').find('tr td:nth-child('+col+')').width(ui.size.width);
            $(this).parent().find('td').height(ui.size.height);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So how you want? Can you describe?

Comment: $(this).closest('table').find('tr td:nth-child('+col+')').width(ui.size.width+'%')

Comment: Need set width in %